# Move between tags in SublimeText

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I would like to move the cursor in between tags in SublimeText. I can't figure out how to do that. Especially in the case of `<test></test>`. If you move the cursor from one end to the other with alt + left/right the cursor will end up moving to these places. `<|test></|test>`. But the cursor will never move in between like this `<test>|</test>`. This marker is `|` is the cursor in this case.

Is there an easy way of doing that?

**Note**: I use OSX

Comment: With Ctrl+left/right you can place cursor between tags. <|test|>|</test|>. First marker is initial position and all others is where cursor will be placed with Ctrl+right.

Comment: For me ctrl + left is a short command for entering the osx dashboard. So perhaps that is Windows specific.

Comment: @black_wizard That doesn't work on my Sublime installation either and I'm in a windows 7 environment.

Comment: in mac ALT+CTRL+ left/right works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the [Emmet-plugin](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) for sublime, you can use the shortcut `ctrl+alt+j` to move between matching tags. Check it out and see if it fits you, Emmet is quite awesome if you do a lot of html by the way.